# How to autopopulate a field when a drop down field value is selected

Tags: list, column

I need to auto populate a filed when a drop down value of another field is selected.

For example , I have a list like this :

```
Bank                     Number 

Unicredit Bank           445565
Banca Italia             345689
```

Then I create a list where I have a form with a drop down field values of bank from the list above an a text box field number.

When a value is selected , for example Unicredit,I want the field number to be autopopulated with the value associated to Unicredit...

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cascading forms is where you need to start and Mark Rackley has a great write-up and youtube video on how to set it up.

1. Upload the script below to our Site Assets Document Library
2. Upload the script below to our Site Assets Document Library
3. Create the “Parent” list used as a Lookup field on our form for the
   cascading drop down list
4. Create the “Child” list used as the Secondary Lookup field on our
   form that has a lookup to the “Parent” list.
5. Edit the script to point to the correct lists and fields for the
   Drop Down list
6. Edit the default New Form for a list
7. Add a Content Editor Web Part to the Form
8. Link the Content Editor Web Part to the script we uploaded in Step 1

[YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_B8rV56-y1s)

[The Scripts](https://github.com/mrackley/HillbillyCascade)

[Link to his site](http://www.markrackley.net/2017/03/06/new-improved-cascading-dropdowns-for-sharepoint-classic-forms/)